# Resolve variable from config-file based on output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a shell script that consist of two files, one bash-file (main.sh) and one file holding all my config-variables(vars.config).

vars.config

```
domains=("something.com" "else.something.com")

something_com_key="key-to-something"
else_something_com_key="key-to-something else"
```

In my code i want to loop through the domains array and get the key for the domain.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
source ./vars.config
key="_key"
for i in ${domains[@]}; 
do
    base="$(echo $i | tr . _)" # this swaps out . to _ to match the vars
    let farmid=$base$key 
    echo $farmid
done
```

So when i run it i get an error message

> ./main.sh: line 13: let: key-to-something: syntax error: operand
>   expected (error token is "key-to-something")

So it actually swaps it out, but i cant save it to a variable.

Comment: If you just want to assign a variable, couldn't you just do `farmid="$base$key"`? i.e. remove the `let`.

Comment: Can you switch `vars.config` to store everything in one associative array? `declare -A domains=([something.com]='key-to-something' [else.something.com]='key-to-something-else')`

Comment: - If i remove the let, the farmid will be stored as "something_com_key" and not the value of something_com_key defined in the config. @RobertSeaman

- I have other variables i want to do the the same with. Like something_com_id, something_com_user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand a variable to the value of its value using `${!var_name}`, for example in your code you can do:

```
key="_key"
for i in ${domains[@]};
do
    base="$(echo $i | tr . _)" # this swaps out . to _ to match the vars
    farmid=$base$key
    farmvalue=${!farmid}
    echo $farmvalue
done
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!